# Global click event in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Im building an app with phonegap, backbone.js and require.js. Each template has the same navigation menu and each header in the templates has a button to slide in and slide out the menu. The menu is displayed with the following code:

```
$('#slide-menu-button').on("click", function (e) {
                var cl = document.body.classList;
                if (cl.contains('left-nav')) {
                    cl.remove('left-nav');
                } else {
                    cl.add('left-nav');
                }
    });
```

I don't want to have to put this code in every view. Where can I put this code so that it's always executed, no matter what template is currently being displayed? Currently I am putting it in app.js which looks like:

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'js/lib',

    paths: {
    app: '../app',
    tpl: '../tpl'
    },

    shim: {
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    }
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'backbone', 'app/router'], function ($, Backbone, Router) {

    var router = new Router();

    $("body").on("click", ".back-button", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.back();
    });

    Backbone.history.start();

    $('#slide-menu-button').on("click", function (e) {

                var cl = document.body.classList;
                if (cl.contains('left-nav')) {
                    cl.remove('left-nav');
                } else {
                    cl.add('left-nav');
                }
    });

});
```

However, this only works for the first template loaded, and not any other subsequent templates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're creating the click event for #slide-menu-button on page load, so it will only register click events with already-rendered elements. You can use the following to apply the event to all elements, including ones that won't render to the DOM until later:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#slide-menu-button", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.back();
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

Backbone should have nothing to do with this type of event. You could bind the listener to the `<body>` element and then add a selector to it. See the jQuery documentation for more info: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('body').on("click", "#slide-menu-button", function (e) {

    var cl = document.body.classList;

    if (cl.contains('left-nav')) {
        cl.remove('left-nav');
    } else {
        cl.add('left-nav');
    }
});
```